# Laravel : undefined index cap tcpdf

Tags: laravel, pdf

```
            $lineStyle = array(
                'color' => $tag['fgcolor'],
                'cap'   => $tag['style']['cap'] ,
                'join'  => $tag['style']['join'] ,
                'dash'  => $tag['style']['dash'] ,
                'phase' => $tag['style']['phase'] ,
            );
```

$tag['style']['cap'] undefined index: cap

Comment: if u do dd($tag) is there a style with a cap in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code below in vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:

```
$lineStyle = array('color' => $tag['fgcolor'] ?? "",'cap'   => $tag['style']['cap'] ?? "",'join'  => $tag['style']['join'] ?? "",'dash'  => $tag['style']['dash'] ?? "",'phase' => $tag['style']['phase'] ?? "",
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory, there is no index `cap` in the array `$tag['style']`.

If you `dd($tag['style']);` you should be able to see it yourself.

If you are using PHP 7.0+, you use the following syntax to set a "default" value in case an index doesn't exist:

```php
            $lineStyle = array(
                'color' => $tag['fgcolor'],
                'cap'   => $tag['style']['cap'] ?? "something" ,
                'join'  => $tag['style']['join'] ,
                'dash'  => $tag['style']['dash'] ,
                'phase' => $tag['style']['phase'] ,
            );
```

The `??` is the null coalescing operator and it is documented here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce

It basically allows you to set a default value in case something doesn't exist.